# PHP Fatal Error is Not Allowing site to be shown

Tags: php

I continue to get the same error:

```
Warning: require_once(/site/web/www/****/finalproject/utils/tags.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/****/public_html/finalproject/utils/main.php on line 20

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
'/site/web/www/****/finalproject/utils/tags.php' 
(include_path='/site/web/www/****/finalproject/') in 
/home/****/public_html/finalproject/utils/main.php on line 20
```

I am not able to edit any of the server config files.  The code in question seems to be:

```
<?php

// Get the document root
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

// Get the application path
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$dirs = explode('/', $uri);
$app_path = '/' . $dirs[1] . '/' . $dirs[2] . '/';

// Set the include path
set_include_path($doc_root . $app_path);
echo $doc_root . $app_path;
echo "<br />";
$include_path = get_include_path();
echo $include_path;

// Get the common code
require_once ('utils/tags.php');
require_once ('model/database.php');
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the include path, but I can't figure it out.  Can someone out there help me?
And yes, this is for a school project, although getting this to work is not part of the assignment per se.  I've been working on it almost all day and am really at my wits end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment might be slightly different to mine, as I don't think it's calling in your `finalproject` path. Running your code gives me the following when debugging (note, I'm on a Linux machine)

```
/var/www/html //$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
/test.php// // echo $app_path
/var/www/html/test.php// // echo $include_path
```

Which is not correct as I don't see the `finalproject` directory anywhere. This is, of course, assuming you have your code running in `/var/www/html/finalproject/`.

A suggestion is that if you have a configuration file or a file that you include everytime sitting on the document root, set the document root variable there. A simple one liner that doesn't rely on the `$_SERVER` variable is:

`$documentRoot = dirname(__FILE__).'/'`

Now we have `/var/www/html/finalproject/` being displayed on output. Better still, set this up as a define:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
// Get the common code
require_once (ROOT_DIR . 'utils/tags.php');
require_once (ROOT_DIR . 'model/database.php);
```

I hope this helps debug your situation.

Comment: Thanks @Cumbo.  That wasn't the complete solution that I was looking for, as I will have to add the `ROOT_DIR` to all of the `require_once` functions, but it's a good enough work around.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Harlan Using the solution above you can still set your include path. `set_include_path(ROOT_DIR);` this will give `/var/www/html/finalproject/` when you output the included path.